# SEVERE error writing to S3 backup

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm running OpsCenter 5.1.1 with Datastax Enterprise 4.5.1. It's a 3-node cluster on AWS and I'm backing up to S3 (still...) I've started seeing a new error. I think this is a different error than any I've posted b4.

`$ cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.8.39 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]`

I am seeing this error in the agent.log file

`node1_agent.log: SEVERE: error after writing 15736832/16777216 bytes to https://cassandra-dev-bkup.s3.amazonaws.com/snapshots/407bb4b1-5c91-43fe-9d4f-767115668037/sstables/1430904167-reporting_test-transaction_lookup-jb-288-Index.db?partNumber=2&uploadId=.MA3X4RYssg7xL_Hr7Msgze.J4exDq9zZ_0Y7qEj9gZhJ570j73kZNr5_nbxactmPMJeKf0XyZfEC0KAplWOz9lpyRCtNeeDCvCmtEXDchH8F1J2c57aq4MrxfBcyiZr
java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3192)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3175)
        at com.google.common.io.CountingOutputStream.write(CountingOutputStream.java:53)
        at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:179)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.writePayloadToConnection(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:308)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.convert(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:192)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.convert(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:72)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.invoke(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:95)
        at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeSyncToAsyncHttpMethod.invoke(InvokeSyncToAsyncHttpMethod.java:128)
        at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeSyncToAsyncHttpMethod.apply(InvokeSyncToAsyncHttpMethod.java:94)
        at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeSyncToAsyncHttpMethod.apply(InvokeSyncToAsyncHttpMethod.java:55)
        at org.jclouds.rest.internal.DelegatesToInvocationFunction.handle(DelegatesToInvocationFunction.java:156)
        at org.jclouds.rest.internal.DelegatesToInvocationFunction.invoke(DelegatesToInvocationFunction.java:123)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.uploadPart(Unknown Source)
        at org.jclouds.aws.s3.blobstore.strategy.internal.SequentialMultipartUploadStrategy.prepareUploadPart(SequentialMultipartUploadStrategy.java:111)
        at org.jclouds.aws.s3.blobstore.strategy.internal.SequentialMultipartUploadStrategy.execute(SequentialMultipartUploadStrategy.java:93)
        at org.jclouds.aws.s3.blobstore.AWSS3BlobStore.putBlob(AWSS3BlobStore.java:89)
        at org.jclouds.blobstore2$put_blob.doInvoke(blobstore2.clj:246)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:494)
        at opsagent.backups.destinations$create_blob$fn__12007.invoke(destinations.clj:69)
        at opsagent.backups.destinations$create_blob.invoke(destinations.clj:64)
        at opsagent.backups.destinations$fn__12170.invoke(destinations.clj:192)
        at opsagent.backups.destinations$fn__11799$G__11792__11810.invoke(destinations.clj:24)
        at opsagent.backups.staging$start_staging_BANG_$fn__12338$state_machine__7576__auto____12339$fn__12344$fn__12375.invoke(staging.clj:61)
        at opsagent.backups.staging$start_staging_BANG_$fn__12338$state_machine__7576__auto____12339$fn__12344.invoke(staging.clj:59)
        at opsagent.backups.staging$start_staging_BANG_$fn__12338$state_machine__7576__auto____12339.invoke(staging.clj:56)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:940)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:944)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$take_BANG_$fn__7592.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:953)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel$fn__4097.invoke(channels.clj:102)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Comment: do you have a partial file in s3 in https://cassandra-dev-bkup.s3.amazonaws.com/snapshots/407bb4b1-5c91-43fe-9d4f-767115668037/sstables/1430904167-reporting_test-transaction_lookup-jb-288-Index.db  ?

Comment: there is a file there: 
    `Bucket:  cassandra-dev-bkup
    Folder:  sstables
    Name:  1430904167-reporting_test-transaction_lookup-jb-288-Index.db
    Link:   [This is a private link] https://s3.amazonaws.com/cassandra-dev-bkup/snapshots/407bb4b1-5c91-43fe-9d4f-767115668037/sstables/1430904167-reporting_test-transaction_lookup-jb-288-Index.db
    Size:  38866048
    Last Modified:  Wed May 06 12:00:58 GMT-400 2015
    Owner:  clutch_point
    ETag:  9f9dd7ae2c2aa9d77ed56c7057f36394-3
    Expiry Date:  None
    Expiration Rule:  N/A`

Comment: On the server (node1), there's a corresponding file: `ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-191:/var/lib/cassandra/data/reporting_test/transaction_lookup$ ls -alrt *Index.db
-rw-r--r-- 2 cassandra cassandra **38866048** May  6 09:22 reporting_test-transaction_lookup-jb-288-Index.db`  -- it's the same size

Comment: So the file on s3 and on your file system ^^ is 38866048 bytes. That does not match 15736832/16777216 bytes from the SEVERE error. can you double check? Might be a different SSTABLE

Comment: I have this `$ cat /usr/share/datastax-agent/conf/datastax-agent-env.sh
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xmx256M"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djclouds.mpu.parts.magnitude=100000"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djclouds.mpu.parts.size=16777216"` 

Is the error because the last part was smaller than the parts.size?

Comment: It just means that there was a file transfer error (network issue) when you were transferring a slice of the sstable (slices are 1677... by default). I'll post a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR -

Your SSTable which is 38866048 bytes, is both on your filesystem and on S3. This means the file has transferred over and you are in good shape. No need to worry about this error (though I opened an internal ticket to handle this kind of exception rather than throw a dump).

**Details - A summary of what I suspect happened**

1) There was a file transfer error when you reached 15736832 out of the 16777216 byte slice of the sstable.

2) At this point OpsCenter did not finish transferring the table or leave a partial version in s3

3) Another backup attempt later on moved the sstable with no error and a valid backup exists.